# Discretization of the Cylindrical Gradients.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need a hand on this doubt I have.
I am modeling a 1D cylindrical incompressible flow with a viscous term $\mu/\rho*(\frac{1}{r}(\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dv_z}{dr})$. This term is a bit of a hustle to discretise especially when employing FDM.

Can I expand the gradient term by chain rule to $\frac{1}{r}\frac{dv_z}{dr}$ + $\frac{\partial^2 v_z}{\partial r^2}$ ?

Comment: Sure, why not...?

Comment: I have searched all over the internet and found none that has been done in such way.